# ActiveAdmin Could not find a valid mapping for AdminUser error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I'm following the instructions here: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/create-beautiful-administration-interfaces-with-active-admin/

So in Step 2, I go to /app/models/admin_user.rb and append the following:
    after_create { |admin| admin.send_reset_password_instructions }

```
def password_required?
  new_record? ? false : super
end
```

So then I go to /admin/admin_users/new and I get the following error when I try to add a user

`RuntimeError in Admin::AdminUsersController#create<br />
Could not find a valid mapping for #<AdminUser id:2, email:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your environments/development.rb ensure your classes are cached:

```
config.cache_classes = true
```

This is not ideal, but necessary in this instance due to a code reloading quirk in Rails, according to comments associated with the bug logged over at GitHub: https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/733

Comment: what i do is leave it false except when I need to ad a new activeadmin admin. Not ideal, but leave it true all the time seems to impede realtime code changes w/o server reboot